# Output text one letter at a time in C

Tags: c

How would I output text one letter at a time like it's typing without using Sleep() for every character?

Comment: Instead of sleeping you could mmm... calculate the first 100000 digits of pi. But sleeping is better. Why don't you want to use it? Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve and why you can't use sleep?

Comment: If I used sleep for each and every character it would be about 10,000 lines of code

Comment: @ChristopherRobbieBarclayKel: Have you tried using loops...?

Comment: He tried using loops but there was too much comparison overhead at run-time. Pretty sure OP is looking for a solution using templates.

Comment: @nw. Is op on an 4004 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping is the best way to do what you're describing, as the alternative, busy waiting, is just going to waste CPU cycles. From the comments, it sounds like you've been trying to manually hard-code every single character you want printed with a sleep call, instead of using loops...

Since there's been no indication that this is homework after ~20 minutes, I thought I'd post this code. It uses `usleep` from `<unistd.h>`, which sleeps for X amount of *microseconds*, if you're using Windows try `Sleep()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void type_text(char *s, unsigned ms_delay)
{
   unsigned usecs = ms_delay * 1000; /* 1000 microseconds per ms */

   for (; *s; s++) {
      putchar(*s);
      fflush(stdout); /* alternatively, do once: setbuf(stdout, NULL); */
      usleep(usecs);
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   type_text("hello world\n", 100);
   return 0;
}
```

Since `stdout` is buffered, you're going to have to either flush it after printing each character (`fflush(stdout)`), or set it to not buffer the output at all by running `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` once.

The above code will print `"hello world\n"` with a delay of 100ms between each character; extremely basic.

Answer (score 2):

Sleep is the best option, since it doesn't waste CPU cycles.

The other option is busy waiting, meaning you spin constantly executing NoOps. You can do that with any loop structure that does absolutely nothing. I'm not sure what this is for, but it seems like you might also want to randomize the time you wait between characters to give it a natural feel.

Comment: For more information, I'm trying to recreate the Portal song "Still Alive" where it's displaying the lyrics in a DOS style window

Answer (score 2):

I would have a Tick() method that would loop through the letters and only progress if a random number was smaller than a threshold I set.

some psuedocode may look like

```
int escapeIndex = 0;
int escapeMax = 1000000;
boolean exportCharacter = false;
int letterIndex = 0;
float someThresh = 0.000001;    

String typedText = "somethingOrOther...";
int letterMax = typedText.length();
while (letterIndex < letterMax){
escapeIndex++; 
    if(random(1.0) < someThresh){
        exportCharacter = true;
    }
    if(escapeIndex > escapeMax) {
        exportCharacter = true;
    }
    if(exportCharacter) {
        cout << typedText.charAt(letterIndex);
        escapeIndex = 0;   
        exportCharacter = false;
        letterIndex++;
    }
}
```

If I were doing this in a video game lets say to simulate a player typing text into a terminal, this is how I would do it.  It's going to be different every time, and it's escape mechanism provides a maximum time limit for the operation.

Comment: It still burns cycles on the random number generator; a few ms delay between loops would be much more polite.